# duplicate key error index in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have a `Page` model as follow and the `page_id` field isn't `unique` but I can't create an instance from `Page` and this error rises 

        `OperationError: Could not save document (insertDocument :: caused by ::11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: shopify.page.$pageId_1  dup key: { : null })`
I have no idea that why the duplicate key error rises when the `page_id` field isn't `unique`

The `Site` model :

```
class Page(Document):

    # page identity
    page_id = StringField()
    store = ReferenceField('Store')
    is_product = BooleanField(default = False)
    is_homepage = BooleanField(default = False)
    product = ReferenceField('Product')
    requests = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Request'))

    # page stat
    visitors = IntField(default = 0)
    views = IntField(default = 0)
    past_days = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('DayStat'))
```

Comment: So you have defined a "unique" key on the field. If not in the class definition then somewhere else by external script. You possibly should be using `required` as an argument on `page_id` since you seem to have supplied a new object without defining a value for that field. And "twice". Hence the duplicate.

Comment: @BlakesSeven at the first the I used `required` as an `page_id`'s argument 
but it doesn't any effect on result !

Comment: Umm. I use Mongoengine myself in various projects. ["Fields"](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#fields) shows all the valid options. i.e `page_id = StringField(required=True)`. But as I said, you already have a "unique" index definition and another item inserted with that field as `null`. You need to find that document and amend it. Plenty of documentation on matching null fields.

Comment: is it possible that this model have another fields except the fields that I write ! except mongoid field 
because the error mentioned that `pageId_1` is the problem and `page_id` was `pageId` in the past @BlakesSeven

Comment: l"index name" and "field name" are not necessarily the same thing. I can see from your class definition that you have not defined an index there. It has been created externally. See how `page_id` did not have a default value and the complaint is that the "duplicate" index is `null` already? That logically points to that field being the problem. Examine the "index" definitions or ask someone in your team who knows how to do this. Or search online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's just because of some old `Document` in database that in past have different fields and when the new changes applied because of different objects type in `Collection` when a function running it unable to recognize  the type of object of field and go down ! 

one solution is dropping the `Collection` and if your `Collection` is too important you can write a script that delete old objects and make a new instance from them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,I also removed the unique=True from the field attribute, and after that dropped the Collection and ran the code again. This resolved the issue.